# Google-maps-react Polyline not showing at all

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I've gone through some similar threads on here but none has helped me. I'm trying to draw a line between some coordinations in React Js using Google Maps API. Please have a look at my code below.

```
<div id="map-container" className="map-container mt-3" style={style}>
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={14}
        style={style}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: 36.164195,
          lng: 5.669404
        }}
      >
        <Polyline
          paths={[
            { lat: "36.160093", lng: "5.668375" },
            { lat: "36.164195", lng: "5.669404" },
            { lat: "36.170509", lng: "5.672011" }
          ]}
          strokeColor="#1E1E1E"
          strokeOpacity={0.8}
          strokeWeight={5}
        />
      </Map>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using a library that provides the `Map` and `Polyline` components or are those components you have written?

Comment: Hi, i'm using google-maps-react library

Answer (score 0):

Replace `paths` prop in Polyline with `path`.